# How to improve the speed of STRREAD()?

Tags: string, performance, matlab, for-loop, cell-array

I have a cell array named 'datetime' as the format below:
2009.01.01 00:00:02.169

this 'datetime' array is 1819833x1 size which is large!!!
I want split it into 2 cell array: 'date' and 'time'.
date='2009.01.01' and time='00:00:02.169'.

So I use the for loop as below:

```
for i=1:numel(datetime)
    [date(i), time(i)] = strread(datetime{i},'%s%s','delimiter',' ');
end
```

As you can see, it use a loop and the speed is really slow when process such a big data.
I try the code this afternoon, and almost ONE HOUR past, the job is still not done....

So can anyone give me a advice?
Thanks!

Comment: Is there anyway to avoid using the for loop?

Comment: Also I aim is to finally turn the 'datetime' cell array into the date serial num.So if there is a better way to do that?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot...It is Matlab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first I would preallocate the `date` and `time`, no mather which solution you pick. Next I did some experiments with the following setup

```
s = '2009.01.01 00:00:02.169';
S = repmat({s}, 100000, 1);
```

The results are

**Using `strread`**

```
tic, for i=1:numel(S), [~, ~] = strread(S{i},'%s%s','delimiter',' '); end, toc
Elapsed time is 3.694143 seconds.
```

**Using `regexp`**

```
tic, for i=1:numel(S), [~] = regexp(S{i},'\s+', 'split'); end, toc
Elapsed time is 1.324754 seconds.
```

**Using `cellfun`**

```
tic, cellfun(@(x) regexp(x, '\s+', 'split'), S, 'UniformOutput', false); toc
Elapsed time is 2.072437 seconds.
```

---

As you can see, most of those approaches are very slow. Fortunately, many functions in MATLAB can use cells directly, watch this:

```
tic, Sresult = regexp(S, '\s+', 'split'); toc
Elapsed time is 0.253819 seconds.
```

You can now access the result by `Sresult{i}{1}` or `Sresult{i}{2}` or simply

```
date = cellfun(@(x) x{1}, Sresult, 'UniformOutput', false);
time = cellfun(@(x) x{2}, Sresult, 'UniformOutput', false);
Elapsed time is 0.835277 seconds.
```

**Ultra Fast Method**

The fastest method I can think of is requiring, that the format is always the same, i.e. the length of each string is equal. In your case, I can imagine it to be true. Then you can use something like this

```
tic, Sa = cell2mat(S); Sdate = Sa(:,1:10); Stime = Sa(:, 12:end); toc
Elapsed time is 0.060586 seconds.
```

Here you get another speed factor of about 20!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach. Not sure how fast it will be:

```
datetime = {'2009.01.01 00:00:02.169'
            '2009.01.02 00:01:05.169'}; %// example data. Cell array of strings
datetime_split = regexp(datetime, '\s+', 'split'); %// split according to spaces
%// Alternatively: datetime_split = cellfun(@strsplit, datetime, 'uniformoutput', 0);
datetime_split = [datetime_split{:}];
date = datetime_split(1:2:end);
time = datetime_split(2:2:end);
```

With the above data, this produces

```
>> date
date = 
    '2009.01.01'    '2009.01.02'
>> time
time = 
    '00:00:02.169'    '00:01:05.169'
```

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks Robert...your advice really helpful!!!
First, I did preallocation, and the time for loop + strread() combination is reduced to **less than 40s** with my 'datetime' array which is 1819833x1 size.

So it is the main improvement, we can see that  the reduce of memory re-allocation and memory data copying can speed up the process a lot....especially when you perform on a large size of sample data.